# Having issues with matplolib for loop getting slower

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to loop over a series of images to see how they change over time. Thus, I want them plotted on the same figure. The following code works but seems to slow down after a few iterations. Does anyone know why this is happening, how to overcome it, or an alternative way to visualize these images over time?

```
fig, ax=pyplot.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
for i in range(n):
    ax.imshow(imageArray[i])
    fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: It is unclear what you precisely want to do here; can you please clarify?

Comment: Something like this? [matplotlib imshow how to animate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212722/matplotlib-imshow-how-to-animate)

Comment: Why don't you follow Jake's tutorial? It is very well done! :)

Comment: The animation is getting slower because the old image isn't deleted. More and more images will be redrawn each time you call 'fig.canvas.draw(). Therefore add `ax.cla()` before the `imshow` call. The tutorial that Jake suggested doesn't need the `cla` because it sets the image directly, and will therefore be slightly faster.

Comment: @titusjan I think that should be an answer

Comment: @david-z: you're right. I made a comment because I don't have time to verify my reply. However, I'm pretty sure this is it, so I now made an answer of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation is getting slower because the old image isn't deleted. More and more images will be redrawn each time you call `fig.canvas.draw()`. Therefore add `ax.cla()` before the `imshow` call. The tutorial that Jake suggested doesn't need the `cla` because it sets the image directly, and will therefore be slightly faster.