# How to animate array with matplotlib imshow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, animation, matplotlib-animation

I have several image numpy arrays in one array (Number of arrays is dynamic) . I want to show them **in a loop and in the same window like animation but infinitely** . However, I want to use **plt.imshow()** for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212722/matplotlib-imshow-how-to-animate and https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/dynamic_image2.html

Comment: These codes don't show interactively. They show end result.In order to see it, you have to save as a video format.

Comment: You can very well modify the parameters of the `funcanmation` to make it run indefinite https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275189/how-can-i-make-points-of-a-python-plot-appear-over-time. and You don't need to save the file that's just examples